# How to boost exact match on multi match in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have several documents with a field name title contain value like `foo bar` and `foo:bar`.
I'm trying to boost an exact match `foo:bar` documents and sort the result according to the score.

Here is my attempt, any help would be appreciated.

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "",
            "fields": [
              "title",
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "",
            "fields": [
              "title",
            ]
            "type": "phrase"
            "boost": 20
          }
        }
      ],
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the mapping of the field `title`? Also why are you using `multi_match` since you're only matching a single field?

Comment: I remove some other field for demo purpose, the type for `title` is `text`